# wget consistently failing over remote connection

Tags: wget, ftp, mobaxterm

I am trying to download a large data set using `wget` which consistently fails.

For context, I am working from home and remote accessing my server using MobaXTerm. The server requires a proxy module to access the internet, for security reasons.

I am using

```
wget ftp2.collab.xyz.ac.uk/my_working_directory/file.txt.gpg --user=USER --password=PASSWORD
```

I receive back:

```
--2020-03-25 09:40:35--  ftp2.collab.xyz.ac.uk/my_working_directory/file.txt.gpg
Resolving proxy.uni.ac.uk (proxy.uni.ac.uk)... 10.95.131.12
Connecting to proxy.uni.ac.uk (proxy.uni.ac.uk)|10.95.131.12|:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2020-03-25 09:41:35 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

I am able to use FileZilla to download to my machine using the same FTP address, user and password. However, this is inappropriate for this large dataset (100s of Gbs) as it would then require reupload to the work server.

Additionally, I cannot download tools to the remote server, such as `lftp`, due to restrictions.

Is there anything I can try to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps the proxy has its own authentication.  One way to specifiy that would be "export http_proxy="h t t p ://username:password@proxy.uni.ac.uk/" (remove the spaces between "h t t p :")

Comment: I've tried that and now it seems to connect but hangs at 'Logging in'?

Comment: Are you intending to do an HTTP request (which `wget` would do by default I believe), or do you want to do an FTP request (you mentioned FTP server)?

Comment: FTP request; I did try and alter the code to `export ftp_proxy="ftp://username:password@proxy.uni.ac.uk:port/"`

Comment: wget knows the parameters --ftp-user and --ftp-password

Comment: What happens if you use a proper FTP URL, as in `"ftp://ftp2.collab.xyz.ac.uk/my_working_directory/file.txt.gpg"`?

Comment: After having done

 `export ftp_proxy="ftp://username:password@proxy.uni.ac.uk:port` I then request the file,

`wget --user=user --password=pass  ftp://ftp2.collab.xyz.ac.uk/my_working_directory/file.txt.gpg
--2020-03-25 12:44:04--  ftp://ftp2.collab.xyz.ac.uk/my_working_directory/file.txt.gpg
           => ‘file.txt.gpg’
Resolving proxy.uni.ac.uk (proxy.uni.ac.uk)... 10.95.131.12|:3128
Connecting to proxy.uni.ac.uk (proxy.uni.ac.uk)|10.95.131.12|:3128... connected.
Logging in as user ...`

Where it hangs